# ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA) , problem reading from memory address

Tags: c++, linux

I'm implementing a simple debugger and I'm trying to read data from a child process memory address with ptrace (for create breakpoint), but I keep getting input/output error.

This is how my program works:

Child process calls to:

```
   ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
   execl(prog_name, prog_name, 0);
```

At this point the child process waits for a signal.

Now the parent process calls to:

```
    errno=0
    uint64_t addrVal = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, m_pid, m_addr, nullptr);
    perror("failed");
```

and there is where it fails.
perror returns input/output error and addrVal keep getting  `0xffffffffffffffff` value.

also, there is might be a chance that im trying to look at the wrong address,
i used objdump to find the address but it seems it just giving me the offset and not the actual address

```
0000000000001165 <main>:
1165:   55                      push   %rbp
1166:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
1169:   48 8d 35 95 0e 00 00    lea    0xe95(%rip),%rsi        # 2005 <_ZStL19piecewise_construct+0x1>
1170:   48 8d 3d e9 2e 00 00    lea    0x2ee9(%rip),%rdi        # 4060 <_ZSt4cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4>
1177:   e8 c4 fe ff ff          callq  1040 <_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@plt>
117c:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
117f:   48 8b 05 4a 2e 00 00    mov    0x2e4a(%rip),%rax        # 3fd0 <_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_@GLIBCXX_3.4>
1186:   48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
1189:   48 89 d7                mov    %rdx,%rdi
118c:   e8 bf fe ff ff          callq  1050 <_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E@plt>
1191:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
1196:   5d                      pop    %rbp
1197:   c3                      retq
```

these are offsets or the actual address?
thanks!

Comment: Since the value returned by a successful PTRACE_PEEK* request may be
       -1, the caller must clear errno before the call, and then check it
       afterward to determine whether or not an error occurred.

Comment: `if(addrVal<0)` can never happen with `unsigned addrVal`. Please post your real code.

Comment: you are right it was a mistake, i fixed it.. but the issue is about ptrace that keep return 0xfffff

Comment: Yes, your are right. It's just offset. You need to add it to the program load address.

Comment: its seems that every time i run my program it loads to different memory address(checked with pmap), how it possible to know where it loads?